# How do I put my public ssh key back to the correct folder on the terminal?

Tags: terminal, finder, ssh

I can't access my login to my remote server which has my domain name stored to it. I believe because I accidentally saved the public key to my desktop instead of the file it's supposed to be in. And since I'm new I don't know how to get it back.

The private key is in the right place when I search for it on my mac terminal, but it's invisible on the mac finder. It's the opposite with the public key, It's visible on the finder.

I have no way of getting into my remote computer as a user unless I have the key working because I disabled the ability to use a username and password to get in. So if I don't figure it out I wouldn't know what to do. :(

I tried moving it back into the folder by dragging it from the desktop into the correct place, but it didn't work. And I tried searching for it on the terminal and it says the file doesn't exist even though I can see it and open it on the mac finder. Which the key opens on the browser with plain text.

I also tried searching for the file .ssh in Go to folder on the finder.

Comment: First, there's no "correct" place for public key.  There are many generally accepted locations, but having it somewhere specific so it works is just not correct.  As far as forcing PKI authentication (which is what you seem to be doing),  it will check keys in a single file: `authorized_keys.   The public keyfile will have nothing t do with this

Comment: Are you talking about the location of the public key *on the remote server*, or on the local client (which I assume is your Mac)? On the local client, the public key is irrelevant, only the private key matters. On the remote server, the public key *must* be in the correct location, or else it (and the corresponding private key) cannot be used, and you'll need some other way to get into the server to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The key files should be in the `.ssh` folder under your home directory. You can use the `cp` command in Terminal to copy the files there.

```
cp key_file key_file.pub ~/.ssh/
```

Replace `key_file` with the actual name of your file.